# value of private static final changes

Tags: java, static

I have been baffled by the below for the past few hours. I have a Fraction class with a constant for the zero fraction, like so:

```
class Fraction{
    private static final Fraction ZERO = new Fraction(0,1);

    public static Fraction zero(){
        return ZERO;
    }
[etc]
}
```

Subsequently, I discovered that the value of ZERO changes in the course of execution, in that:

```
System.out.println(Fraction.zero());
Fraction half = new Fraction(1, 2);
System.out.println(Fraction.zero());
```

outputs:

```
1/1
1/2
```

while obviously the value produced should be 0/1, and, more importantly, fixed.
The problem is definitely not with the implementation of the Fraction class and the GCD calculator associated to it, since I have used them successfully and extensively in the past.

Any ideas and thoughts on the cause of this strange behaviour are much appreciated.

Comment: [Minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) please, or it didn't happen!

Comment: the rest of the code plz

Comment: See also: http://ideone.com/vyK81.

Comment: The cause of the problem was in the incorrectly put `static` modifiers for the numerator and denominator variables. Points on the phrasing of my question (i.e., SSCCE) duly noted, in the future I will try to supply all relevant information from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should show us the rest of the code in the class - my guess would be that the numerator and denominator variables have been marked as `static` while they really should have been regular instance variables.

Whatever the problem is, there is nothing wrong with the contents of an object referred to by a `final` field changing - the `final` modifier only ensures that the field cannot be made to refer to another object. The object itself is unprotected.

Comment: Especially, show the constructor -- since that's the code being called that appears to change the value -- and the declarations of the members that it modifies.

Comment: Thanks, the numerator and denominator were indeed static. This solved it; in the static/final respect I (as I now once more realise) was a novice when writing this class originally.

Comment: @NominSim: Unless it's been edited and I'm not seeing what you're seeing, it's definitely an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet,assylias It has been edited, originally it only had the initial suggestion to show the rest of the code.

Comment: @NominSim: It initially had only the first paragraph, but it did include the `static` suggestion all of the time - it was _speculative_, but I felt that it was the only probable explanation, which is why I took the chance of posting it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: The OP was asking why the `final` value changes, which is correctly addressed in your second paragraph, your first is speculative as you say, and doesn't really address the OPs question directly. In any case my down vote can't be removed until an additional edit is made to your answer.

Comment: @NominSim: True enough; however, I'm under the impression that SO encourages answers that address "what the OP really wanted" in cases where the OP is wrong about the cause of the problem. The second paragraph answered his literal question, but it was the first paragraph that actually helped him find the error - guess which paragraph he found to be the most valuable. :-) Never mind about the downvote, though.

Comment: My fault for thinking that what the OP had asked was not the question that they actually wanted an answer for :)

Comment: @NominSim: Hehe - after all, most questions in here are from people that are stuck on some problem, and the good questions also include a theory about what is wrong (which will often be the basis for the title and the tags) - however, resolving the problem is usually the top priority for the poster, even if the resolution is different from what the poster thinks it will be. :-)

Comment: If I may say something, my question was for people to point to possible causes for such behaviour. This is exactly what @AasmundEldhuset kindly provided. In passing, my understanding of the `static` and `final` modifiers was also enhanced. In the future, I will try to be more concrete in my questions. Thanks all.